# x range invalid in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, simulation, data-analysis

I am trying to plot some data in gnuplot using this script[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV6VX.png)

but gnuplot shows the x range invalid dialogue.
What's wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

int/int returns as int in gnuplot. All t values are 0, therefore all your x range is from 0 to 0. Try to add a point after 1, e.g do `1./10` instead of `1/10`.